# Italicising Fictional Company names throughout

Tags: formatting

If I have created a fictional theatre with it’s own name, and italicise the name with it’s first appearance in the story, do I need to keep it in italics whenever it’s mentioned after that?

Eg: We made our way to *The New Grand Duchess Theatre*. I was excited. It had been closed down for years...

(Later in story)

....I couldn’t wait to tell Henry all about *The New Grand Duchess Theatre* in all her renovated glory.

So basically, does the theatre’s name need to be kept in the same format  or can I lose the italics after it’s first mentioned?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Sally, glad you found us  Please check out our [tour] and [help].